# JavaScript JSON parse by a given key without looping

Tags: javascript, json

Given a JSON string as this:

```
{
    "__ENTITIES": [
        {
            "__KEY": "196",
            "__STAMP": 1,
            "ID": 196,
            "firstName": "a",
            "middleName": "b",
            "lastName": "c",
            "ContactType": {},
            "addressCollection": {
                "__deferred": {
                    "uri": "/rest/Contact(196)/addressCollection?$expand=addressCollection"
                }
            },
            "__ERROR": [
                {
                    "message": "Cannot save related entity of attribute \"ContactType\" for the entity of datastore class \"Contact\"",
                    "componentSignature": "dbmg",
                    "errCode": 1537
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there a method to get just the `__ERROR` record, I know I can use 
`var mydata = json.parse(mydata)` and then find it from the `mydata` object.  But I was hoping there was a method to only return the `ERROR` field something like
`json.parse(mydata, "__ERROR")` and that gets only the information in the `__ERROR` field without turning the whole JSON string into an object

Comment: Unfortunately there is no official spec for a JSON schema, and so you must loop through your data. Of course, if you're confident that the shape of your data will look as described above, you can use: `JSON.parse(response).__ENTITIES[0].__ERROR[0].message` but this isn't really advised.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *"Is there a method to get just the `__ERROR` record, I know I can use `var mydata = json.parse(mydata)` ... But I was hoping there was ... something like `json.parse(mydata, "__ERROR")`"*

There may be libraries that do this, but nothing built in. You need to write code that targets the data you want.

The closest you'll get will be to pass a reviver function to `JSON.parse`.

```
var errors = [];

var mydata = JSON.parse(mydata, function(key, val) {
    if (key === "__ERROR")
        errors.push(val);
    return val
});
```

Comment: Nice usage of the `reviver` parameter! Yet you might use `return undefined` to discard all the unused data.

Comment: @Bergi: True if the rest of the parsed data isn't wanted. Or `undefined` could be returned for just the `__ERRORS`.

Answer (score 1):

If such a function existed, it would have to parse the whole thing anyway, to find the key you're looking for.

Just parse it first, then get the key you want:

```
var mydata = JSON.parse(mydata);
var errorObj = mydata.__ENTITIES[0].__ERROR[0];
```

If you want, you may create your own function:

```
function parseAndExtract(json, key) {
    var parsed = JSON.parse(json);
    return parsed[key];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> without turning the whole json string into an object

That's hardly possible, you would need some kind of lazy evaluation for that which is not suitable with JS. Also, you would need to write your own parser for that which would be reasonable slower than native `JSON.parse`.

> Is there a method to get just the __ERROR record

Not that I know. Also, this is an unusual task to walk the whole object tree looking for the first property with that name. Better access `__ENTITIES[0].__ERROR[0]` explicitly.